# error in phpmyadmin after updating to PHP 7.2.0

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, php-7.2

Recently I update my PHP version to 7.2.0 .
When I open my phpmyadmin I have face this warning every time when i open **any table** in database.
[image: error in phpmyadmin]

If anyone have know about it, Let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the version of your MYSQL?

Comment: @MpdelaVega mysql version is 5.7.11

Answer (score 6):

I have the same issue. Take care about the error. If you see the image the warning are on the line 601, in my case was on line 613.

To solve edit sql.lib.php

change this line:

```
|| (count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'] == 1)
```

By:

```
|| (count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1
```

Regards and happy new year 2019 !

Comment: This was on line 615 for me, despite the error indicating that the problem was on line 613.

Answer (score 2):

This `#601` error was also tied to `#532` line error too in my case.
The additional #532 complication is phpmyadmin’s attempt to try to count some parameter, invalid in newer PHP versions as they can’t use `count()` or `sizeof()` with an `array` type.

Edit `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php` `line #532` in whatever text editor you please. find this erronous code:

`if ($options != null && count($options) > 0) {`

Force parameter to array is easy way to solve this:

`if ($options != null && count((array)$options) > 0) {`

*big thanks [@chaloemphonthipkasorn](https://medium.com/@chaloemphonthipkasorn) for the suggestions*

Answer (score 1):

Up your PMA to the last version

https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/pull/13414/commits/4b037582d9ac1686f2c4ba5e05d4ab61729d570a

Answer (score 1):

https://launchpad.net/~nijel/+archive/ubuntu/phpmyadmin

> Note: This repository is currently a bit behind as I struggle to find time to update it to 4.7 series, see https://bugs.debian.org/879741. There are no severe security vulnerabilities in the 4.6.6 currently packaged here (https://www.phpmyadmin.net/security/PMASA-2017-9/ applies only to 4.7 series). The only major problem is that 4.6.6 doesn't work properly with PHP 7.2.

It will have this error for php7.2 at the moment.

You can manually download/unzip the phpmyadmin and install in your server.

Answer (score -2):

if you have an existing or old version of phpMyAdmin configuration on your computer, always check if you already remove or make sure that the old files/history of the config is fully or successfully deleted/already empty in order for your newly installed/updated config to work properly with no any bugs or errors. After you make sure that the old file configuration is already clean, your existing version of phpMyAdmin will be replaced by the version you've configured.

For more information. See this link: https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#upgrading-from-an-older-version